# Redirect one Wordpress page from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have checked all of the related questions I can find in here (and in Google in general), and tried all of the various solutions given, but haven't been able to get this to work.

I am working on a Wordpress site that has recently gone SSL. I have set it up so that all pages are forced to https by adjusting the Settings page in the Admin area, adding the appropriate line to the wp-config file to force the admin side to be https and have modified my htaccess files to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/branding/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^branding/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Here's what I would like this to do...
1) `http://www.example.com/` (and any sub pages except branding) gets redirected to `https://example.com`
2) `http://example.com/branding` stays as it is
3) `https://example.com/branding` is redirected to `http://example.com/branding`

The above htaccess code works to force the http: to https:, however, if I enter either `http://example.com/branding` or `https://example.com/branding` I am redirected to `https://example.com`.

I have used numerous variations of the initial Rewrite code and placed it in various places (as instructed in various other answers to similar questions here) with no change to the result.

If anyone can tell me where my error is and how to fix it, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a colleague, we got it worked out. Here's the updated code...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/branding/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/branding/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The WP-specific rules in the htaccess file cause some strange situations to occur.  The main one being that there is an internal rewrite from /branding/ to /index.php, and then WP handles the request within the PHP.  The file checks will handle the check to ensure that the index.php file exists.  WP will internally deal with redirecting valid page requests that don't have trailing slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/branding/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^branding(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/branding$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. Using that code it tells me I have a redirect loop when I go to either http:example.com/branding or https:example.com/branding. If I add the trailing /, both redirect to https://example.com (the home page).

Comment: It seems like this is the part of the code that isn't functioning properly...
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/branding/`

Comment: May be, try removing `/` from the end.

Comment: Tried that as well. No change. Everything still redirects back to the home page. Any other thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Been searching for this for hours... Here is the tweak if you need to redirect **more than one page** to http from https.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page1|page2|page3/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1|page2|page3/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```